# Suppress display in a column if the value is equal to the value in another column

Tags: query

I have 2 date columns that are displayed side-by-side. I have some dates that are equal. I do not want to display the "equal" dates/duplicate date values in one of the columns.

Example:

```
    column1     column2
    1-1-2014    1-1-2014
```

I want to display:

```
    column1     column2
    1-1-2014
```

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

See the DDL, DML and SQL below, it should get you some (all?) of the way. It's taken from MySQL, but should be fairly generic.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select) (MS SQL Server) and also [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) (more general). Check the docco of your particular server for any or all which may apply.

```
CREATE TABLE fred 
(
  billy int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  d1 date DEFAULT NULL,
  d2 date DEFAULT NULL
);

mysql> desc fred;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| billy | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| d1    | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| d2    | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into fred values(1, '20140606', '20140607');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> insert into fred values(1, '20140606', '20140606');  <<<=== SAME
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into fred values(1, '20140607', '20140608');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> select * from fred;
+-------+------------+------------+
| billy | d1         | d2         |
+-------+------------+------------+
|     1 | 2014-06-06 | 2014-06-07 |
|     1 | 2014-06-06 | 2014-06-06 |  <<=== SAME
|     1 | 2014-06-07 | 2014-06-08 |
+-------+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT billy, d1, 
  CASE
    WHEN d1 = d2 
      THEN NULL
    ELSE 
      d2
  END AS d2 
FROM fred;

+-------+------------+------------+
| billy | d1         | d2         |
+-------+------------+------------+
|     1 | 2014-06-06 | 2014-06-07 |
|     1 | 2014-06-06 | NULL       | <<== ***
|     1 | 2014-06-07 | 2014-06-08 |
+-------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering your table's name is "date_table", then you can select like this

```
SELECT date_table1.`column1`, date_table2.`column2`
FROM date_table AS date_table1
LEFT JOIN date_table AS date_table2 
                     ON date_table1.`column1` = date_table2.`column1` 
                     AND date_table1.`column2` = date_table2.`column2` 
                     AND date_table1.`column1` != date_table2.`column2`
```

Answer (score 1):

T-SQL (SQL Server) has a built-in function for this purpose, NULLIF().

```
SELECT leftcol AS a, NULLIF(rightcol, leftcol) AS b
FROM myTable;
```

If rightcol equals leftcol, the NULLIF() expression in column b will return a NULL value. I'm sure there are similar functions in other SQL dialects as well.